# Using MagicMock to test the inner components of a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I'm new to using the mock library and unit testing in general.  I think I understand how the mock library works, but I think there is something wrong with my approach.

Lets say I have a class `Foo` that has a method `addFoo(bar1, bar2)` and `addFoo` calls other 'private' methods within foo, but can also raise exceptions at various parts in the code... i.e.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
         # This creates lots of dependencies

    def _inner1(self, bar):
        if this_doesnt_work:
           return None
        return modified_bar1

    def _inner2(self, bar2):
        if this_doesnt_work:
           return None
        return modified_bar2

    def addFoo(bar1, bar2):
        if self._inner1(bar1) and self._inner2(bar2):
           #do something
        else:
           raise SomeException
```

When I unit test, what I currently do is mock out `Foo.__init__` in my unit test setup and set `return_value` to None.  This works and allows me to run tests against my methods in the class without all the external dependencies and just mock any class attributes with my mocked `Foo.__init__` instance.

After that is done if I wanted to unit test `addFoo` I would do the following (skipping a bunch of steps):

```
@patch.object(Foo, '_inner2')
@patch.object(Foo, '_inner1')
def test_inner1_exception(self, mock_inner1, mock_inner2):
    mock_inner1.side_effect = Exception
    # then do some asserts to make sure it worked
```

**QUESTION**
How do I test an exception in `addFoo` if the code looks like this:

```
def addFoo(bar1, bar2):
    bars = self._getBars() #something that returns a list
    my_modified_bar_list = []
    for bar in bars:
        my_modified_bar_list.append(self._inner1(bar))

    if len(my_modified_bar_list) == 0:
        raise SomeException
```

In this instance how do I test `SomeException` when it is dependent upon the values produced by some array within my method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html) you can [assert about expected exceptions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) as follows:

```
@patch('Foo._getBars', return_value=[])
def test_addFoo_exception(self):
    foo = Foo()
    with pytest.raises(SomeException):
        foo.addFoo(Mock(), Mock())
```

As snippet above shows, by mocking `_getBars` you are in control of what it is returned and can therefore force the condition that triggers the exception in your code, in this case an empty list.

I have written a short [post with common unit testing pitfalls in Python](https://esaezgil.com/post/unittesting_pitfalls/) that you might find useful.